# Problema al leer un xml con php

Tags: php, xml

Tengo el siguiente problema, a la hora de leer un **xml** de una factura me esta presentado un **Warning** con un formato de factura en especifico. Esto no me esta sucediendo con otro grupo de facturas que si las puedo procesar. A continuación les dejo el **Warning** que me esta generando.

**Warning:**

> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct():
>   tmp/CAMF840207IB3-20180108T181935.xml:20: namespace error :
>   xmlns:schemaLocation: 'http://www.sat.gob.mx/registrofiscal
>   http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/cfdiregistrofiscal/cfdiregistrofiscal.xsd'
>   is not a valid URI in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/cajachica/models/archivo_model.php on line 75

**Código de la linea 75**

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($path."/".$archivo,null,TRUE);
```

La linea donde se me está generando el error es la siguiente:

```
<cfdi:Complemento>
<registrofiscal:CFDIRegistroFiscal xmlns:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/registrofiscal http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/cfdiregistrofiscal/cfdiregistrofiscal.xsd" Version="1.0" Folio="XXXXXXXXXXXX" xmlns:registrofiscal="http://www.sat.gob.mx/registrofiscal"></registrofiscal:CFDIRegistroFiscal>
```

La sección del código donde estoy registrando al **namespace**:

```
 $xml->registerXPathNamespace('reg',$namespaces['registrofiscal']);
```

Comment: Se está repitiendo `http://www.sat.gob.mx/` en la url. Por eso te dice que la URL no es válida.

Comment: Prueba sin el `$path` o define bien si es ingresando a `registrofiscal` o `sitio_internet`

Comment: Depura/revisa las variables `$path` y `$archivo`. Si en algunas casos te funciona el mismo código y en este no, significa que hay algún problema con esas variables, al parecer aquí: la variable `$path` está adquiriendo el valor: `'http://www.sat.gob.mx/registrofiscal http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/cfdiregistrofiscal/`... hay que buscar el motivo.

Comment: El valor que eme esta devolviendo la variable **$path** es el siguiente : **tmp/CAMF840207IB3-20180108T181935.xml** en otras facturas también me viene repetido **http://www.sat.gob.mx/** y si me la esta procesando sin problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esto me funcionó para leer los CFDI que traen en el complemento 
registroFiscal:CFDIRegistroFiscal

```
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

    $xml= new \SimpleXMLElement($xml_file, null, true);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta si me soluciono el problema.

Answer (score 1):

También me ayudo mucho poner la linea

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true); 
$xml= new \SimpleXMLElement($xmlname, null, true);
```

Ya que esto me sucedía con los CFDIs (que inician con AAA) que estos fueron timbrados con contraseña, en lugar de FIEL. Hacen referencia a una página del SAT que intenta accesar a un objeto que no puede ser leído por el servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Ojo, porque en las facturas que son complemento de pago el Folio está en el complmento;

```
foreach ($xml->xpath('//cfdi:Comprobante') as $cfdiComprobante){ 
     $NoFactura=$cfdiComprobante['Folio']; 
     $Fecha=$cfdiComprobante['Fecha']; 
     $Metodo=$cfdiComprobante['FormaPago']; 
     $Subtotal=$cfdiComprobante['SubTotal']; 
     $Total=$cfdiComprobante['Total']; 
} 

//***********Código para el caso del complemento de pago
if(!$NoFactura){
    foreach ($xml->xpath('//reg:CFDIRegistroFiscal') as $Complementos) {
        $NoFactura=$Complementos['folio']; 
    }
}
```